# No se muestra instersticial en Fragment

Tags: android, admob

estoy intentando mostrar el interstitial en una página fragment pero no se reproduce, este es el código que uso:

```
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
public void displayInterstitial() {
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        interstitial.show();
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_recent_wallpaper, container, false);

    // Buscar AdView como recurso y cargar una solicitud.
    AdView adView = (AdView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    // Crear el intersticial.
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(getActivity());
    interstitial.setAdUnitId("ID_ADMOB");

    // Crear la solicitud de anuncio.
    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    // Comenzar la carga del intersticial.
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                displayInterstitial();

            Intent intslider = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivitySlideImage.class);
            intslider.putExtra("POSITION_ID", position);
            intslider.putExtra("IMAGE_ARRAY", allArrayImage);
            intslider.putExtra("IMAGE_CATNAME", allArrayImageCatName);

            startActivity(intslider);

        }

    });

return rootView;
}
```

Alguien sabe porque no se muestra el anuncio??

Comment: Hugo, obtubviste tu ad_unit para el anuncio o para testing?

Comment: Como te comenta @Elenasys, tienes que agregar un id de anuncio válido, es similar a esto:      `interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-91724593812982876/0972091012");` (Esto es solo un ejemplo), eso lo obtienes cuando  creas tu anuncio en google.

Answer (score 1):

Es importante agregar un verdadero Ad Unit o el desplegado en el LogCat:

```
interstitial.setAdUnitId("ID_ADMOB");
```

En tu código la carga del anuncio esta relacionado a dar click en el Grid, lo cual no veo conveniente:

```
grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

                displayInterstitial(); //Este método trata de cargar el anuncio.
                ...
                ...
```

Hay que tomar en cuenta que la creación del Fragment tarda un poco, por esta razón sería bueno agregar un listener y si no esta cargado el anuncio, forzar el cargado:

```
 interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            if (interstitial.isLoaded()) 
            interstitial.show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            super.onAdClosed();
            //interstitial.loadAd(request.build());
        }
    });

    // Comenzar la carga del intersticial.
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: Ha ya claro, eso lo he cambiado para no publicar mi ID de admob, ese código funciona bien en un activity normal pero al usarlo en un fragment no se muestra, y no se si es que hay que utilizar otro código para mostrarlo en un fragment

Comment: Gracias por comentar, porque no ves conveniente poner el anuncio en el grid? yo quiero que cuando se pulse la imagen salga un intersticial. He probado tu código pero este lo que hace es mostrar un intersticial al iniciar la app, y eso no lo puedo poner asi.

Comment: Hola Hugo, simplemente porque el mostrar el anuncio no debe depender de una acción, si eso te piden como requisito para tu app esta bien, pero es un poco "raro". Agrega el listener prueba y me comentas.

Comment: @HugoAE Solo cambia de lugar las funciones: En el escuchador de tu grid coloca:  `if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
                    interstitial.show();
               } else {
                   //Volver a tu fragment de gridView
                }`

Comment: He probado tu código, pero me muestra el intersticial sin hacer ninguna acción, y a ver yo tengo entendido que el anuncio intersticial debe mostrarse al hacer una acción por ejemplo pulsar una imagen, ya que si por ejemplo lo muestro a los X segundos de abrir una página, sin hacer ninguna acción eso está penalizado por google,

Comment: Pon el listener dentro del onItemClick.

Comment: Vale también lo puse pero así no hace nada, @x4mp73r también probé poner tu código pero sigue sin mostrarse el anuncio, tal vez sea porque no lo puedo poner en el GRID? ya que si los pongo en otro lugar si se muestran